# How to bind the Thymleaf table column value to Java bean object

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have calculated the sum of the column of the table in jQuery and return the total value to thymeleaf view. How can i set the total value to in a Java model object.

JQuery Code:

```
$(function(){

       var grandTotal= 0;
       $("[id*=BuildingAsf]").each(function(){
           grandTotal=grandTotal+parseFloat($(this).html());
         //  alert( $( this ).text() );
       });

       totalBuildingAsf.html(grandTotal);
   });
```

HTML Code :

```
`<tr><td th:text="#{apx1_p1_pu_row_1_lbl}"></td>
 <td id="total-Building-asf" class="total-Building-asf" th:text="*{entityDetailRow.totalAsfBuilding.formattedValue}"></td></tr>`
```

Comment: You can pass your calculated total inside  $("#total-Building-asf").text(grandTotal). But if you wants to bind the value to java model and pass to server then the approach is little bit different. Post your full thymleaf code for better understanding.

Comment: From jQuery I am able to get the total calculated value . however that value is not able to bind with the model object . Here is the my thymeleaf class     .<form id="mainForm" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> <div id="private-use-table" class="section-rounded-corners-std section-margin-bottom-std"  <table class="table-std"> <tbody><tr>  <td th:text="#{apx1_p1_pu_row_1_lbl}"></td> <td id="total-Building-asf" class="total-Building-asf" th:text="*{entityDetailRow.totalAsfBuilding.formattedValue}"></td> </tr> </tbody></table> </div>

Comment: You have to understand that jQuery works in the user's browser. For the total to be reflected in the model object then it has to be posted to the server via Ajax Post.